# vault-secrets-provider alias not recognized with terraform-vault template

Tags: gitlab, hashicorp-vault, terraform-template-file, to-be-continuous

I'm having some issues when trying to use Hashicorp vault template (with terraform  to.be.continuous).

Actually when I use it with terraform-vault template I got an error message.

This is a summary of .gitlab-ci.yml

```
include:
 - project: "to-be-continuous/terraform"
    ref: "2.4.0"
    file: "templates/gitlab-ci-terraform.yml"
 # Vault variant
  - project: 'to-be-continuous/terraform'
    ref: '2.4.0'
    file: '/templates/gitlab-ci-terraform-vault.yml'

variables:
  VAULT_BASE_URL: "https://vault.secrets.tech.orange/v1"
  VAULT_ROLE_ID: $VAULT_ROLE_ID
  VAULT_SECRET_ID: $VAULT_SECRET_ID
  GCP_MYSECRET: "@url@http://vault-secrets-provider/api/secrets/XXX/gcp/credentials?field=mygcpsecret"
```

Error Message:

```
[ERROR] Failed getting secret GCP_MYSECRET:
... Connecting to vault-secrets-provider (127.0.0.1:80)
... wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I tried without vault template and it works.

Would you please help me with this? Or perhaps, where I can ask for some help?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/. That also works with CE.

Comment: @Helene
Issues with Vault can be tough to analyse. I think `404` is probably due to a wrong secret path or a wrong field (the query parameter).
I recommend you to follow the [How to test & debug](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/tools/vault-secrets-provider/#how-to-test-debug) chapter from **to be continuous** doc to troubleshoot your problem...

Comment: Anyway you wouldn't have a `404` if GitLab CI wasn't recognising the `vault-secrets-provider` host alias. It's definitely an issue in the secret path :)

Comment: It is not a problem of path but an issue en vautl template. 2 services are listening on port 80. An issue has been opened

Comment: You're right, two services are listening on port 80, but on different hostnames (service aliases). I'm 90% sure 404 is answered by the right service (vault secrets provided). Could you perform some troubleshooting please? This way you will get an explicit error message.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you were facing this issue due to a Kubernetes runners limitation.

As stated in [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html),

> Kubernetes runners cannot use several services using the same port

As a result, using the tracking service in addition to another one using the same port (80) fails.

[It has now been fixed](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/tools/tracking/-/merge_requests/11).